# Java Guessing Game count total guesses

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

so I am having trouble with being able to have a proper **TOTAL guess counter**.

My code needs to be basic so please dont offer me advice for doing anything you think is not trivial. 
Currently,

1. my code plays a game, then asks the user if they want to play again and its a simple Y or N.
2. If yes, another games plays
3. If no then then game ends and it reports the results of every game played as such: `the total games, guesses per game, and the best game (reports game that had lowest guess count)`.

My issues are being able to accurately count **ALL THE GUESSES** from every game. I am able to report results and track the total games played correctly but I can't figure out how to report a result that tracks the guesses per game, adds them all up, finds the smallest one.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGame {
  public static final int MAX = 100;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); //to use scanner
  Random r = new Random(); //to use random numbers

  intro(); 
  int totalGuesses = guess(console, r); 

  System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");
  String answer = console.next();
  int plays = 1;
  //while loop reads user input and determines wether 
  //or not to play the game again
  while(answer.charAt(0) == 'y' || answer.charAt(0) == 'Y') {  
     System.out.println(); 
     guess(console, r); 
     System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");  
     answer = console.next();
     plays++;  
  } 
  System.out.println();
  results(plays, totalGuesses); 
  }     

      }

       //method that creates the guessing game and congratulatory message
     public static int guess(Scanner console, Random r) {
      System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between one and " + MAX + "...");
        int theNumber = 50; //creates a random answer between one and the MAX       class constant

     int userGuess = 0;//establishes the integer for the user's guess
    int guesses = 0; //establishes the amount of guesses 
     int totalGuesses = 0;
    while(userGuess != theNumber) { //while loop that executes until answer is correct
     System.out.print("Your guess? ");
     userGuess = console.nextInt();
     if(userGuess > theNumber) {
        System.out.println("It's lower.");
     } else if (userGuess < theNumber) {
        System.out.println("It's higher.");
     }
     guesses++;        
  }
  if(guesses == 1) {
     System.out.println("You got it right in 1 guess!");
  } else {
     System.out.println("You got it right in " + guesses + " guesses!");
  }
  totalGuesses += guesses;
  return totalGuesses; 
   }

   //prints out the stats of the game
   public static void results(int plays, int totalGuesses) {
      System.out.println("Overall results:");
      System.out.println("Total games = " + plays);
      System.out.println("Total guesses = " + totalGuesses);
      System.out.println("Guesses/game = ");
      System.out.println("Best game = ");
   }

}
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger. Concentrate on the places where you expect `totalGuesses` to be updated. I think you will see it (maybe even without debugging). P.S. 'Guess' seems to be one of those odd words which looks wronger the more often you see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable called "guesses" must be created in the main class, not inside the guess method.
Then, just add it to the method ( public static int guess (scanner,random,int guesses))

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `guesses` and `totalGuesses` needs to be instantiated outside of the method. Put `int guesses` and `int totalGuesses` just above

`public static int guess(Scanner console, Random r) {
    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between one and " + MAX + "...");`

so that it is like this

`int guesses = 0;
int totalGuesses = 0;
public static int guess(Scanner console, Random r) {
    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between one and " + MAX + "...");`

and remove them from inside of the class so that its like this.

```
 int userGuess = 0;//establishes the integer for the user's guess

while(userGuess != theNumber)
```

You should also add `guesses = 0;` in the main class here.

```
  System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");  
     answer = console.next();
     plays++;  
     guesses = 0;
  }
```

Comment: But when I put the `int guesses` and `int totalGuesses` outside of the method I get an error message that says "non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"  
What does this mean exactly??

Answer (score 0):

Here's the whole code in one main method. Maybe it'll shed some light.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();
    int MAX = 100; //ceiling for the random number
    int total = 0; //total number of guess
    int plays = 0; //total number of games
    int bestGame = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //used to determine game with lowest amount of guesses
    String answer; //holds user input

    boolean playing = true; //used to determine if the game is ongoing

    while (playing) { //while game is ongoing
        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between one and " + MAX + "...");
        int theNumber = r.nextInt(MAX) + 1; //generate random int [1, 100]
        int userGuess = 0; //holds user guess
        int guesses = 0; //total number of guesses this game

        while(userGuess != theNumber) { //while number is not guessed
            System.out.print("Your guess?\n");
            userGuess = console.nextInt();
            if (userGuess > theNumber) System.out.println("It's lower.");
            else if (userGuess < theNumber) System.out.println("It's higher.");
            guesses++; //increase guesses this round by 1
        }

        if (guesses < bestGame) bestGame = guesses; //if we used less guesses than in our best game this is our new best game
        System.out.println("You got it right in " + guesses + " guess(es)!");

        plays++; //increase number of games by 1
        total += guesses; //increase total guesses by guesses this round

        System.out.println("Again?");
        answer = console.next();
        if (answer.toLowerCase().equals("n")) playing = false; //if input is n (or N) we exit the loop
    }

    console.close(); //close scanner

    System.out.println("Overall results:"); //print results
    System.out.println("Total games = " + plays);
    System.out.println("Total guesses = " + total);
    System.out.printf("Guesses/game = %.2f%n", (double) total/plays); //cast to double to prevent integer division
    System.out.println("Best game = " + bestGame);

}
```

Comment: what is the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` ?  my knowledge is super basic

Comment: The maximum value an `int` can represent (2147483647).